# High accuracy on LSTM-RNN model implemented on time-series forecasting

Tags: python-3.x, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am new in LSTM-RNN. I have tested many RNN-LSTM python code with .csv files for time-series. None of them had the accuracy that this guy here: https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/ has. How can he achieves that with just 4 LSTM cells?

```
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(1, look_back)))
```

Am I missing something here? Is there something wrong in the code? I am referring to his first example code: "LSTM Network for Regression"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember this article from years ago (it's from 2016). Don't expect too much from this. It's just a tutorial with toy data.

The author later half-acknowledged that data was too small, had bias and the model was greatly overfitted, which is easily spottable from the graph where predictions and ground truth are just lagging from each other. It's always a bad sign.

You can get that from the comments if you search for "bias, "lookahead" or "overfit".

Comment: So, If I have that the predicted results are approaching the unseen dataset, shifting a bit in y-axis, but they have exactly the same shape, this is sign of overfitting?

Comment: Yes it mostly looks like a "ghost / echo". Also specifically for time series, watch out not to peek inadvertently "in the future".
See some explainations here for instance: https://medium.com/@soumyachess1496/cross-validation-in-time-series-566ae4981ce4

Comment: This guy (I am referring to my posted link) plots real dataset + prediction on trained data + prediction on unseen data. If the real dataset is "covered" with prediction of both trained data and unseen data, and I don't see any shifted echoes is that a reliable model?

Comment: The dataset is only 144 observations: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/airline-passengers.csv
So, really easy to overfit.